# Terminate a gnome-terminal opened with subprocess

Tags: python, terminal, subprocess

Using subprocess and the command '`gnome-terminal -e bash`' I can open up a gnome-terminal as desired (and have it stick around). This is done with either

```
p=subprocess.Popen(['gnome-terminal', '-e', 'bash'])
```

or

```
p=subprocess.Popen(['gnome-terminal -e bash'], shell=True)
```

but I cannot close the terminal using `p.terminate()` or `p.kill()`. From what I understand, this is a little trickier when using `shell=True` but I did not expect to run into problems otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To terminate a terminal and its children (in the same process group):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import signal
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(['gnome-terminal', '--disable-factory', '-e', 'bash'],
                     preexec_fn=os.setpgrp)
# do something here...
os.killpg(p.pid, signal.SIGINT)
```

- `--disable-factory` is used to avoid re-using an active terminal so that we can kill newly created terminal via the `subprocess` handle
- `os.setpgrp` puts `gnome-terminal` in its own process group so that `os.killpg()` could be used to send signal to this group

Comment: Is there a way to go about this without `--disable-factory`? I'm trying to make this optionally work with xterm, which does not have the `--disable-factory` option.

Comment: @Shatnerz: I don't know how `xterm` works. You could ask a separate Stack Overflow question about `xterm` case specifically.

Comment: Just an update: --disable-factory is no longer supported, at least as of version 3.28.2. I'm still interested in the answer to this question since this solution didn't work for me!

Comment: @JamesPaulMason: the code in the answer works as is on my Ubuntu machine with GNOME Terminal 3.28.2.

Comment: Just tried on two different systems. It worked on Ubuntu with gnome-terminal 3.18.3 but not RedHat with gnome-terminal 3.28.2 using VTE 0.52.2 +GNUTLS. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this workaround:

- get the process id
- kill the process

**Working Solution: Close gnome-terminal-server**

As suggested by @j-f-sebastian in the comment, gnome-terminal

> just sends the request (to `gnome-terminal-server`) to start a new terminal and exits immediately -- there is nothing to kill the process is already dead (and newly created processes are not descendants:  the new `bash` process is a child of `gnome-terminal-server`, not `gnome-terminal`).

```
import subprocess
import os, signal
import time

p=subprocess.Popen(['gnome-terminal -e bash'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
print "this is going to be closed in 3 sec"
time.sleep(3)
# this line returns the list of bash instances pid as string
bash_pids = subprocess.check_output(["pidof", "bash"])
# I get the last instance opened
pid_to_kill = bash_pids.split(" ")[0]
os.kill(int(pid_to_kill), signal.SIGTERM)
```

My solution is following this logic:

- run gnome-terminal
- get the latest bash instance opened process id
- kill this process id

**Broken solutions**

These solutions might work in simpler  cases:

**Solution 1**

```
import subprocess
import os, signal

p=subprocess.Popen(['gnome-terminal -e bash'], shell=True)
p_pid = p.pid  # get the process id
os.kill(p_pid, signal.SIGKILL)
```

In order to choose the  appropriate method of signal to pass instead of *SIGKILL* you can refer the [signal documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/signal.htm). E.g.

> On Windows, signal() can only be called with SIGABRT, SIGFPE, SIGILL, SIGINT, SIGSEGV, or SIGTERM

For Unix you have a quite extensive list of method to call.

To have a better overview about **os.kill**,  you can refer [its documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.html).

**Solution 2**

An alternative method useful for Unix could be:

```
import subprocess
import os, signal

p=subprocess.Popen(['gnome-terminal -e bash'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
os.killpg(os.getpgid(p.pid), signal.SIGTERM)
```

It seems that your process is opening child process that prevent the parent to be close. Adding a [session id](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/setsid.html) to your parent process, you should be able to fix it.

**Solution 3**

```
import subprocess, psutil

def kill(p_pid):
    process = psutil.Process(p_pid)
    for proc in process.get_children(recursive=True):
        proc.kill()
    process.kill()

p = subprocess.Popen(['gnome-terminal -e bash'], shell=True)
try:
    p.wait(timeout=3)
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
    kill(p.pid)
```

This solution requires [**psutil**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil/).

**Solution 4**

According to [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/327381/quit-all-instances-of-gnome-terminal-via-a-command), it seems that the best way to close a gnome terminal instance would be to execute a bash command like:

```
killall -s {signal} gnome-terminal
```

where {signal} simulates Alt + F4.

You can try to do it using [**pexpect**]:

```
p = pexpect.spawn(your_cmd_here)
p.send('^F4')
```

Comment: I tried exactly what you said in an ipython terminal. The opened terminal was not closed.

Comment: I guess I found it.  I edited the answer adding the sessions id and closing using os.killpg instead of os.kill

Comment: So, this looks like progress. I can copy and past the code exactly. No terminal pops up. I assume it is destroyed immediately. However, I add a 3 second sleep, and the terminal is never destroyed, even at completion of the script. It looks like nothing happens when I try using the interactive python shell

Comment: Another option might be to use [psutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil/). I will write another example in the answer so you can give a try!

Comment: downvote. None of the solutions work with `gnome-terminal`. On my system `gnome-terminal` is a starter application that does not wait for the actual terminal to exit: it just sends the request (to `gnome-terminal-server`) to start a new terminal and exits immediately -- there is nothing to kill the process is already dead (and newly created processes are not descendants:  the new `bash` process is a child of `gnome-terminal-server`, not `gnome-terminal`).

Comment: Hi @j-f-sebastian, would you have any suggestion on how to get gnome-terminal-server pid in order to kill it?

Comment: Hi @Shatners , eureka! Now it is working and I tested on my python 2.7 console on ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I didn't say that `gnome-terminal` launches `gnome-terminal-server` (it is likely exists already). You should remove broken solutions (or indicate clearly what solutions are broken).

Comment: Do you think it's clear now? Can you remove the down vote?  Thanks for your help in this answer

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add this snippet for anyone who is running on Linux Ubuntu and trying to open a subprocess, run a script, and terminate it after a time.wait().

I found a litany of solutions that would open a window, but not close it. Or a solution would open a window, and close it, but wouldn't run the script inside the terminal.

There was no exact answer so I had to hack together several solutions, as I am a novice when it comes t subprocess/shell.

This snippet was able to open a subprocess, run the script, and when 10 seconds had passed the subprocess was terminated. Again, this was built ofn the shoulders of giants. I hope this saves someone time; cheers.

```
            import os
            import signal
            import subprocess
            import time

            command = 'python3 Rmonitor.py'
            p = subprocess.Popen(['gnome-terminal','--disable-factory', '--', 'bash', '-c', command],preexec_fn=os.setpgrp)
            time.sleep(10)
            os.killpg(p.pid, signal.SIGINT)
```