# kill process do not kill the subprocess and do not close a terminal window

Tags: python, subprocess, popen, gnome-terminal

I am working on UBUNTU and I have file `main.py` with a code inside:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding=utf-8
import os
import time
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, call, signal

base_path = os.path.abspath('')
path_to_file = base_path + '/test_subprocess.py'
p = Popen(['gnome-terminal', "--",  path_to_file])
time.sleep(2)

os.kill(p.pid, signal.SIGKILL)
```

I have `test_subprocess.py` with code like that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding=utf-8

import time

def print_message():
    while True:
        print('I am working!')
        time.sleep(0.5)
    
print_message()
```

I tried to kill the subprocess but after

```
os.kill(p.pid, signal.SIGKILL)
```

subprocess is still working and prints `'I am working!'`

How can I finish subprocess and how to close gnome terminal?
If I selected completely wrong way. Can you show me working example?

New version of `test_subprocess.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding=utf-8
import sys
from subprocess import signal
import time

def print_message():
    while True:
        print('I am working!')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        if signal.SIGKILL:  # it is braking a loop when parent process terminate!
            print('I am killing self!')
            break

print_message()
```

Should I do it like above?

Comment: Does signal.SIGKILL in test_subprocess.py fix my problem? I have checked and it is closing subprocess. Is that all what i need?

Comment: Please don't add additional questions (and answers) into the question. Each question page should be about a single question. Changing/adding your question might invalidate existing answers - please avoid that. If you have a new question, you can [ask another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following:

```
p = Popen(['gnome-terminal', "--",  path_to_file])
PIDs = p.pid
os.system("kill {0}".format(PIDs))
```

> Popen.pid The process ID of the child process.
>
> Note that if you set the shell argument to True, this is the process
> ID of the spawned shell.

http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html

This will at least kill the correct process. Not sure if it will close the terminal.

**Edit:** to kill the process *and* close the terminal:

```
p = Popen(['gnome-terminal', '--disable-factory', '-e', path_to_file], preexec_fn=os.setpgrp)

os.killpg(p.pid, signal.SIGINT)
```

Credit to https://stackoverflow.com/a/34690644/15793575, whih I modified for your command:

- `--disable-factory` is used to avoid re-using an active terminal so that we can kill newly created terminal via the subprocess handle
- `os.setpgrp` puts gnome-terminal in its own process group so that
  `os.killpg()` could be used to send signal to this group

Comment: This: p = Popen(['gnome-terminal', '--disable-factory', '-e', path_to_file], preexec_fn=os.setpgrp)

os.killpg(p.pid, signal.SIGINT) is working for me. But what to do if in child process you have to do something before a closing? For example if you have  open files or you have to save your work befor you close a program?

Comment: HOW TO RUN PYTHON SCRIPT AS SUBPROCESS IN VENV?

Comment: I found answer in os.environ in child process. If i call parent in env, child is called in env.

Answer (score 0):

> [Popen.pid](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html)
> The process ID of the child process.
>
> ***Note that if you set the shell argument to True, this is the process
> ID of the spawned shell.***

Try setting the `shell` argument of the `Popen` constructor to `False`. (`p = Popen(['gnome-terminal', "--",  path_to_file])` -> `p = Popen(['gnome-terminal', "--",  path_to_file], shell=False)`). I had a similar issue not long ago - this fixed it for me.

Comment: Hello. I tested with shell=False, but doesn't help me. When parent program is finished, child is still working.